# how to configuring or save index.html in specified folder with Serenity BDD and Maven

Tags: maven, rest-assured, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I want to store main report file index.html with timestamp in specified folder with Serenity BDD and Maven. and I want to hide the other files which are getting generated along with index.html file. can't we just generate a single emailable index.html report file.

referred to the below link and followed the steps but its copying the entire site folder.
https://johnfergusonsmart.com/configuring-different-output-directories-serenity-bdd-maven/

Comment: This is what you want. (emailable report) https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/extended-reports.html#_serenity_emailable_reports The default report can't be displayed correctly if other files are missing.

Comment: Thank you will try this documentation. if I come across any issues will reach out.